# VBA Excel Chart DataLabels Show Run-Time Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write subroutines for two different pie shaped chart. One works fine on DataLabel ShowValue and ShowPercentage but on second subroutine I get Run Time Error. here is the code:

```
Sub Grafik_5()

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Grafikler").Range("C7:C9")
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Grafikler!$A$7:$A$9"
With ActiveChart.Parent
    .Height = Range("C113:C123").Height
    .Width = Range("C113:E113").Width
    .Top = Range("c113").Top
    .Left = Range("c113").Left
End With
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels
    .ShowValue = False
    .ShowPercentage = True
End With
End Sub
```

It gives error on ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels line

Appreciate all help,
Thanks,

Comment: @Viyata tried that same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `ApplyDatalabels` before working with them. This should resolve the error.

```
Sub Grafik_5()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Grafikler").Range("C7:C9")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Grafikler!$A$7:$A$9"
    With ActiveChart.Parent
        .Height = Range("C113:C123").Height
        .Width = Range("C113:E113").Width
        .Top = Range("c113").Top
        .Left = Range("c113").Left
    End With
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
        .ApplyDataLabels
        .DataLabels.ShowValue = False
        .DataLabels.ShowPercentage = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You can also use `.HasDataLabels = True` instead of `.ApplyDataLabels`. It makes no real difference, but the former seems somehow better to me.